# Nginx pass proxy to url as: http://example.com/test/app

Tags: url, nginx, reverse-proxy

I am trying to configure Nginx as a proxy to http://example.com/test/app

My config is similar to this :

```
server {
    listen 80;
    location  / {
        proxy_pass http://example.com/test/app;
    }
}
```

I am getting 301 response. I don't think this is something related to the web app the proxy is referring to, because its url is accessible via the browser.

I am quite new to Nginx. Please help. :)

Answer (score 1):

please try the following bare minimum configuration:

```
server {

  listen 80;

  location / {

  proxy_set_header        Host $host;
  proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

  # Fix the "It appears that your reverse proxy set up is broken" error.
  proxy_pass          http://example.com/test/app;
  proxy_read_timeout  90;

  }
}
```

Please note that security aspects are missing in this example.